# Make Image Link Openable In New Tab

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML template :

```
<div class='item'>
    <img href='...' attributes='...' \>
    <div class='popup' attributes='...'>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use Jquery to on mouse over of the div (and thus the image), and show the popup. The problem is, I can't seem to control+click to open in a new tab in chrome nor firefox; neither can I right click the image and open the link in a new tab. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jQGmE/)**

Here's the code markup with an example of an image (ctrl+click on it and it will take you to google.com):

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" attributes="#"\>
    </a>
    <div class="popup" attributes="#">
    </div>
</div>
```

You just needed to wrap your `<img>` tag with an `<a>` tag.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That did it perfectly!  
An addendum - how can I stop the main page from proceeding to the link a new tab just opened for?

Comment: The main page shouldn't be doing anything if you pressed (ctrl+click), unless you have some js working there once you clicked on the image, meaning a js `event`

Comment: I did have some old JS messing with that. Thanks for your assistance and have a nice day, Luis.

Comment: @geogaddi Ah ok, hmmm well if you have any trouble, post a new question and we will try to help! You're welcome, nice day for you too!

Comment: It was just some old code lingering around, nothing worth documenting! :)

Answer (score 8):

Add `target="_blank"` to the link. It should look something like this:

```
<div class='item'>
    <a href='...' target="_blank"><img src='....' attributes='...' \></a>
        <div class='popup' attributes='...'>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link that you want the image to open goes in `a href='LINK'` and the file path to the image goes in `img src='PATH'`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
<div class='item' >
    <a href='...' attributes='...' target="_parent">
    <img src="yoursource.jpg"/></a>
    <div class='popup' attributes='...'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add target="_parent" or you could use _blank to your href (and remove the img for now), then close the href with > and make and new img field.  wrap your href and img with   Should work now

Comment: `target` is not a valid attribute of `div` in HTML5 or HTML4.

Comment: It's still not valid and neither is an `href` on an `img`.

Answer (score 1):

Surround your image with `<a>` tags and link to a new page which has the image on it.